# android How to show 25 row in multi column list view and when click on next button show next 25 row

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I have a multi column list view and data retrived from sqlite database. i want to display only 25 rows in my list view and when user will click on next button the next 25 row will be display. so what i do for display 25 row and hide prev button and when click on next button next 25 row display and enable prev button.

My code is here

DBHelper.jav

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAlldata(){
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "select * from entry_table order  by date(entry_date)";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // you are creating map here but not adding this map to list
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++) {
                      //  map.put(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));}

                    map.put(FIRST_COLUMN, c.getString(4));
                    map.put(SECOND_COLUMN, c.getString(2));
                    map.put(THIRD_COLUMN, c.getString(5));
                    map.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, c.getString(6));
                    map.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, c.getString(7));
                    map.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, c.getString(3));

                    // so do add it here
                    maplist.add(map);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
            return maplist;
        }
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
    TextView txtFifth;
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);


        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
        txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item3);
        txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item4);
        txtFifth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item5);

    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
    txtFifth.setText(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

ReportView.java

```
public class ReportView extends Activity{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Button btnPre, btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.report_view);
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_btn_pre);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_btn_next);
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);


        final ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        list = db.getAlldata();

        final ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long idInDB) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HashMap<String, String> rowData = (HashMap<String, String>)adapter.getItem(position);
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ReportView.this);
                dialog.setTitle(rowData.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_date);
                TextView txt2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_ledger);
                TextView txt3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_Particuller);
                TextView txt4 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_income);
                TextView txt5 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_expenses);

                txt1.setText(rowData.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
                txt2.setText(rowData.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
                txt3.setText(rowData.get(SIXTH_COLUMN));
                txt4.setText(rowData.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
                txt5.setText(rowData.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

                dialog.show();              

            }

        });

        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ????
            }
        });
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ?????
            }
        });

    }
```

activity image is here
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea.
[sushildlh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5305430/sushildlh) idea would be easy and clean but it you should be careful if you are having too many rows in your database.
My solution would be,
On the database query store the last extracted row value, possibly for the date column and on the next query add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement.

```
static int lastRaw=-1;

//on database query
String query;
if(lastRaw==-1){
   query = "select * from entry_table order  by date(entry_date) DESC LIMIT 25";
}else{
   query="Select * from every_table WHERE date<"+lastRow+" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25";
}
```

After the query call the adapter's notifyDatasetChanged() method.

**More Explanation**;

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAlldata(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query;
        if(lastRow==-1){
             query="select * from entry_table order  by date(entry_date) DESC LIMIT 25";
        }else{
             query="Select * from every_table WHERE date<"+lastRow+" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25";
        }
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // you are creating map here but not adding this map to list
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++) {
                  //  map.put(c.getColumnName(i), c.getString(i));}

                map.put(FIRST_COLUMN, c.getString(4));
                map.put(SECOND_COLUMN, c.getString(2));
                map.put(THIRD_COLUMN, c.getString(5));
                map.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, c.getString(6));
                map.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, c.getString(7));
                map.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, c.getString(3));

                // so do add it here
                maplist.add(map);

                //update the last row value here
                //you can use the date field considering its an Integer or you could use the BaseColums._id column of your table. Choose a comfortable way to store the last selected row based on how you created your table.
                lastRow=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return maplist;
    }
```

At button onclick;

```
//by going through your code I noticed that you've to declare the adapter before you declare the btn.onClick  for this to work
// onClick can have a code something like this
list=db.getAlldata();
//check whether list is empty. It can be empty if you have reached all the data in the database
if(list.size>0){
     adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}else{
     //you have no more results
     lastRow=-1;
     //you can choose to hide the Next button if you want.
     v.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}
```

The above code was not tested.

P.S.  Although I've not included in my answer I would highly recommend you to make your database call in a new thread. I didn't include that because in your code you've just used the same UI thread.

Comment: brother, plz tell some more

Comment: and how to use Button for next view

Comment: What do you mean? The last update I added was the piece of code you mich need to implement inside your next buton's onClick method.

Comment: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from cursorWindow which has 4 rows, and 8 column

Comment: Which line gives the error? Appears that you've a column missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Cursor Adapter

Below is a good start

> https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

If you are flexible to move to recyclerview use Cursor Adapter with recyclerview